# How to make H.264 file fast-forwardable in Android application?

Tags: java, android, video, h.264, gstreamer

I am an intern at company and my 'learning task' is to make Android application in Java, which takes H.264 format videos (at first they will be stored at SD card) and make like a very simple player, which would have the following features:
1.You can pause/play/fast-forward/fast-backward video
2.When you are at certain point of video and it is stopped, you can switch to the same time in a different video (same picture frame index i guess).

How could i do that? Is using Gstreamer a good way? I looked at the poor tutorial available on net and because of my lack of experience in video processing (I've never worked with video in Android applications) I have quite a hard time understanding what is pipelines, also the JNI and even setting up Gstreamer for Eclipse. Is there a better way of doing this? What should I get to know before starting to mess with this program?
Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your mentioned features are possible in Gstreamer, however, there is a learning curve.

To understand the GStreamer android tutorials, you must first go through the basic tutorials here: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorials

If you feel comfortable with the pipeline architecture, then go ahead and set up your android environment (which is no easy task by itself). Gstreamer is a very very powerful framework where you can do almost anything, if you're willing to make the effort to overcome the learning curve.

So i suggest to go ahead in gstreamer only if you have the time and patience, else go for a simpler solution. Unfortunately i'm not familiar with android, so i cannot suggest any. maybe a quick google search will help.